# Previous activity brought to foreground when tapping fast

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a situation where Activity A has started Activity B, and then B launches activity C and finishes itself, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main.class);
intent.putExtra("GAME_TYPE", Game.MULTIPLAYER);
intent.putExtra("GAME_DATA", data.toString());
intent.putExtra("GAME_ID", gameId);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This normally works fine and C is brought to the front. When the user closes C, A is revealed.

The problem arises if the user taps repeatedly on the screen while B is finishing and C is launching. This seems to cause A to come to the foreground, with C successfully launched in the background (LogCat output indicates that C is running).

My guess is that B finishes and reveals A, which is brought into focus by the tapping, before C has had the chance to launch. Is this likely to be the cause of the problem? If not, what is? How can I prevent this from happening and ensure that C is brought to the front even if the user is tapping wildly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your code and xml is structured but a simple workaround would be to make the layout that activity A is running in to not be clickable after onStop is called.

Another thing I would suggest is to check how activity B finishes and C starts. Are you calling finish on B before C starts? Does C need to load a lot of data which is causing the delay? If so consider waiting on some or all of that heavy data to load and then launching C.

Not much else can be said without any source code.